# hasMany relation without table having id column

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I am using `CakePHP 2.5`. I am having following table

**CompanyMaster:**

- company_master_id [PK]
- Name and other columns

**CompanySignatoryDetails: (has many owners for single company)**

- company_signatory_details_id [PK]
- company_master_id [FK]
- Name and other columns

Now, I want to get company details with all owners of that company. Here is what I have tried.

```
$this->CompanyMaster->bindModel(
    array(
        'hasMany' => array(
            'CompanySignatoryDetails' => array(
                'className' => 'CompanySignatoryDetails',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'CompanySignatoryDetails.company_master_id = CompanyMaster.company_master_id'
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);


$this->CompanyMaster->recursive = 2;

$company = $this->CompanyMaster->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array('CompanyMaster.*'),
    'conditions' => $conditions,  //company id in condition
));
```

I am getting following error:

```
Database Error 
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'CompanyMaster.id' in 'field list' 

SQL Query:
SELECT `CompanyMaster`.*, `CompanyMaster`.`id` FROM      `crawler_output`.`company_master` AS `CompanyMaster` WHERE `CompanyMaster`.`company_master_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Please let me know how can I bind model without `id` as column name.

Comment: Have you properly defined the non-standard primary key in your `CompanyMaster` model class?

Comment: @ndm Actually my question lead me to define non standard primary key. Got it now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP will produce a separate query when dealing with `hasMany` relationships, and therefore you won't be able to reference a field from another table. Only `belongsTo` and `hasOne` relationships produce a `JOIN`.

However, you don't need to add conditions to the relationship. The following should just work fine:

```
$this->CompanyMaster->bindModel(array(
    'hasMany' => array(
        'CompanySignatoryDetails' => array(
            'className' => 'CompanySignatoryDetails',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_master_id',
        ),
    )
));
```

Don't forget to define your primary keys for `CompanyMaster`:

```
class CompanyMaster extends AppModel 
{
    public $primaryKey = 'company_master_id';
}
```

and for `CompanySignatoryDetails`:

```
class CompanySignatoryDetails extends AppModel 
{
    public $primaryKey = 'company_signatory_details_id';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for instance, let your query looks like this:

> ```
> select CompanyMaster.*,CompanySignatoryDetails.* from
> CompanyMaster as cm inner join CompanySignatoryDetails as cd on  
>     cm.company_master_id=cd.company_master_id  
>       order by cm.company_master_id;
> ```
>
> You will get all fields from two tables, ordered by company_master_id field. You may reduce number of fields, displayed by this query, by explicitly designate them like this:

```
select cm.company_master_id, cd.name from....
```

HNY!(Happy New Year!!)

Comment: HNY to you too! I can do that query manually. But I wanted to do it using `CakePHP`